# Java Integer auto auto-boxing

Tags: java, integer, autoboxing

I have stumbled upon this in Java (JDK 1.7):

```
    Integer a = 100;
    Integer b = 100;
    Integer c = 1000;
    Integer d = 1000;

    System.out.println(a == b); //true
    System.out.println(c == d); //false
    System.out.println(new Integer(100) == new Integer(100)); //false
    System.out.println(new Integer(1000) == new Integer(1000)); //false
```

The output is:
true
false
false
false

Why does a==b evaluate to true? What is the reason for this? Is this similar to String internalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this similar to String internalization?

Yes - essentially all integers that can fit in a byte (-128 to +127) are interned and thus share the same underlying object. Larger ones aren't, and thus *probably* don't share the same underlying object (this is covered in JLS 5.1.7) - though note that there's nothing in the spec that prevents larger integers sharing the same underlying object if someone were to choose to implement a VM that way.

I would imagine the rationale is that "smaller" integers in this range are used much more often than larger ones, so using the same underlying objects is worth it to reduce the potential memory footprint.

In your `new Integer(100) == new Integer(100)` example, this isn't the case since you're explicitly creating new integer objects, similar to how `new String("hi") == new String("hi")` evaluates to false.

Just to re-iterate - when comparing integers like this in all real world scenarios, then `.equals()` should be used (or preferably still, == with primitive integers unless there's a good case for using the object type.)

Comment: This isn't a common mistake, but it is a good reason to use the native Java types for numbers, booleans, etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is because all small integers are cached (like for String internalization), so you get the same instance when you boxe them.

From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) :

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the
>   range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127
>   (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing
>   conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

And the additional notes enlighten on the compromise that was made :

> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an
>   identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using
>   existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic
>   compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values
>   always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may
>   cache these, lazily or eagerly. For other values, this formulation
>   disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on
>   the programmer's part. This would allow (but not require) sharing of
>   some or all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the
>   desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially
>   on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for
>   example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long
>   values in the range of -32K to +32K.

Comment: Thank you. How small does an integer need to be? What is the main reason to do this, performance and memory footprint?

Answer (score 1):

values from -128 to 127 are cached

`java.lang.Integer` has a inner static class that caches all Integer objects between -128 and 127